# Is there a simple way to enumerate indices of an Array in Base?

Tags: julia

Sometimes one wants to loop over the indices of an Array. For example, suppose I want to create a noisy multiplication table. First, create some noise:

```
julia> m = 0.1*rand(2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0692654  0.0297861  0.0642931
 0.0187022  0.0530222  0.0561437
```

Next, add the values of the table:

```
julia> indices(A) = Iterators.map(Tuple, CartesianIndices(A))
indices (generic function with 1 method)

julia> noisy_mult = [i*j+m[i,j] for (i,j) in indices(m)]
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.06927  2.02979  3.06429
 2.0187   4.05302  6.05614
```

Is there an `indices` equivalent in Base, or a better/simpler way to achieve the same result? Will adding `indices` to the standard library be a good idea?

Comment: I think you could get the desired behavior with broadcasting in many cases: `axes(m, 1) .* axes(m, 2)' .+ m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a workaround for the following error message for CartesianIndices:

```
iteration is deliberately unsupported for CartesianIndex. 
Use `I` rather than `I...`, or use `Tuple(I)...`
```

I would ask whoever wrote that message about the disadvantages if any of adding such a way around it.

Comment: I agree. The splat `...` is costly for performance, so this error might be a way to force people into more performant implementations. But from the lack of other suggestions, I feel the `indices` utility function in OP can be useful.

Comment: I certainly seems efficient enough to me.

Comment: Accepting this answer, as it seems to be the endpoint of the discussion.