# Create a matrix where values are 1 one the outer most rows/cols and increase towards the center

Tags: matrix, julia

As the title says, I want to create a matrix where values are 1 one the outer most rows/cols and increase towards the center.

Here is as far as I have gotten:

```
dims = (5,5)
m1 = zeros(Int, dims)

for i in 1:dims[1], j in 1:dims[2]
    m1[i,j] = (min(i,j))
end

5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  2  2  2  2
 1  2  3  3  3
 1  2  3  4  4
 1  2  3  4  5
```

I then tried using various upper and lower triangle functions to copy/paste parts of the triangle but no joy. What I want:

```
5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
     1  1  1  1  1
     1  2  2  2  1
     1  2  3  2  1
     1  2  2  2  1
     1  2  1  1  1
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the last row of the matrix?

Comment: Oh, yes! that 2 should be a 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using a conditional to tell if you're past the diagonal and behave accordingly:

```
for i in 1:dims[1], j in 1:dims[2]
    if  (i + j) < dims[1] + 1
      m1[i,j] = (min(i,j))
    else
      m1[i,j] = min(dims[1] - i + 1, dims[2] - j + 1)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another answer:, which also provides an example for using a function I've suggested in [Is there a simple way to enumerate indices of an Array in Base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191746/is-there-a-simple-way-to-enumerate-indices-of-an-array-in-base)

```
julia> indices(A) = Iterators.map(Tuple, CartesianIndices(A))

julia> dims = (5,5)

julia> [min(minimum.(zip(I,dims.-I.+1))...) for I in indices(dims)]
5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  2  2  2  1
 1  2  3  2  1
 1  2  2  2  1
 1  1  1  1  1

julia> dims = (4,4,3)
(4, 4, 3)

julia> [min(minimum.(zip(I,dims.-I.+1))...) for I in indices(dims)]
4×4×3 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1

[:, :, 2] =
 1  1  1  1
 1  2  2  1
 1  2  2  1
 1  1  1  1

[:, :, 3] =
 1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1
```

As shown, this method generalizes to higher dimensional arrays naturally, and it will work with non-square arrays too.

DNF managed to get rid of some slowing allocations (see his answer), and so:

```
[min(t..., (dims .+ 1 .- t)...) for t in indices(dims)]
```

is a simple rewrite of his code using the `indices` shortcut.

Comment: This is nice, but _very_ slow.

Comment: @DNF Couldn't quickly figure out how to avoid arrays popping up (instead of only tuples). It should be doable and then result in faster code. Any suggestions? (I'll incorporate in answer)

Comment: I wrote a separate answer below. I didn't realize until afterwards how similar your solution was.

Comment: @DNF added your version of the function, but still trying to promote the `indices` notation ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple one-liner, that is also very fast:

```
foo(N) = [min(i, j, N+1-i, N+1-j) for i in 1:N, j in 1:N]
```

For more generality, and almost as good performance, try

```
bar(dims...) = [(t=Tuple(i); min(t..., (dims .+ 1 .- t)...)) for i in CartesianIndices(dims)]
```

It is quite similar to @DanGetz's solution, but avoids `zip`, and uses `Tuple` instead, which seems advantageous for performance.